# How to differentiate string and json in Postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In Postgres SQL,

```
SELECT json_field, user_id, pg_typeof("json_field")
FROM some_table
WHERE user_id = 1234;
```

When I make the above query I'm getting the below response(Copied the JSON from popSQL), where for some fields the value is string and for some it is json although the pg data type is same for both. Is there any way to differentiate between both kind of values in postgres

```
[
  {
    "json_field": {},
    "user_id": 1234,
    "pg_typeof": "jsonb"
  },
  {
    "json_field": {},
    "user_id": 1234,
    "pg_typeof": "jsonb"
  },
  {
    "json_field": {},
    "user_id": 1234,
    "pg_typeof": "jsonb"
  },
  {
    "json_field": "{}",
    "user_id": 1234,
    "pg_typeof": "jsonb"
  },
  {
    "json_field": "{}",
    "user_id": 1234,
    "pg_typeof": "jsonb"
  }
]`
```

Comment: Can you provide create table script of some_table?

Comment: Datatype "object" does not exists in PostgreSQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html